# Control file download with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, iframe

I am creating a page that initiates a download of a PDF after a JS counter reaches 0.

On this page I have an iframe that calls a PHP with the following code to force the download of PDFs:

```
<?php
$file     = urldecode($_POST['url']);
$parts    = explode('/',$file);   
if($file){
  header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
  header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
  readfile($file);
  echo 'Yes';
}else{
  echo 'No';
}
?>
```

The question is: how can I know exactly which download has started?

I need the parent iframe to do actions just when the download starts, but I do not know how to do it.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

1. Script which echoes file writes somewhere name of file that was given (Reddis, text file or etc.)
2. Main page were all iframes were run from makes ajax requests to some script (ajax.php) that checks that temporary storage with filename,
3. If download has begun temp storage contains some value - ajax.php echoes filename and removes it from temp storage.
4. Main page does logic according to received value.

Hope this could help you.